# Why do the equations $Ax + By + Cz= D$ represent planes in $\Bbb R^3$ and not lines?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I was wondering why $$Ax+By+Cz=D$$ represents a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because from my perspective it seems that it could simply also represent a line in  $\mathbb{R}^3$. And, yes, I do acknowledge that lines aren't three-dimensional, but surely we can have lines in three-dimensional space.

Comment: Look at $z = y - x$. When $z = 0$, you have $y = x$. This is what the curve looks like in the $xy$ plane. Increasing the values of $z$, you have $y = x + z$, a collection of lines. Sure you can have lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but you would have to parametrize them.

Comment: Recall that a plane has two "degrees of freedom", whereas a line only has one "degree of freedom".

Comment: you can think that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a line is the intersection of two planes.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: any equation puts a condition on the possible values of (x, y, z), that they must satisfy that equation.  One equation, that must be satisfied by all (x, y, z), reduces the dimension of the set by 1.  In the plane, which has dimension 2, one equation reduces that to 2- 1= 1 dimension, a line.  $R^3$ has dimension 3 so one equation reduces that to 3- 1= 2 dimensions,  a plane.

Comment: 2D plane ie collection of lines in 3D space for different values of Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a line in three dimensions you need *two* such equations. The reason is that a line is one dimensional object, so you must apply two constraints to reduce the three dimensional space to a one dimensional object. If you only apply a single constraint, you are left with $3-1= 2$ degrees of freedom, leaving you with a two dimensional object, in this case a plane.

In general, in a $n$ dimensional space, you'll need to write down $n-1$ equations to describe a line, $n-2$ to describe a plane, etc.

**N.B**
This of course has a linear algebra connection: If we have $n-k$ independent linear equations, the rank of the matrix in the resulting matrix equation is $n-k$, and therefore the dimension of the null space must be $k$. In other words, the object described is spanned by $k$ vectors.

Comment: Can you generally define what "a degree of freedom" is please.

Comment: @ReinhildVanRosenú - loosely, "a degree of freedom" = a variable. For instance the point $(6,7,9)$ has zero degrees of freedom, but the set of all points $(x,y, 0)$ has two and describes a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the succinct and consciece answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you know about dot product, the above equation can be written as (assume $C\neq 0$)

$$ \langle A, B, C\rangle \cdot \langle x, y, z - \frac{D}{C}\rangle = 0$$

Thus $(x, y, z)$ satisifies $Ax+By+Cz = D$ if and only if the vector from $(0,0,\frac{D}{C})$ to $(x, y, z)$ is perpencidular to $\langle A, B, C\rangle$. The set of all such $(x, y, z)$ will be a plane passing through $(0, 0, \frac DC)$ with normal $\langle A, B, C\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

how about write it in another form like $Ax + By = D - Cz$, and treat z as a constant.

If $z = 0$, we get a line, if $z=1$, we get anther line.

When change $z$ from minus infinity to positive infinity.  We got lots of lines, which makes them a hyperplane. Maybe you can draw them on a paper.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how we can magically move from having one line to two lines simply by making z=1 as a constant.

Comment: take a book, view the book as 3-d cubic. Each page as a 2-d  xy plane and z is  number of pages. Then for each z from 1 to n, you can draw a line in each page.

Comment: Your method cannot explain why, e.g., $Ax +By = D - Cz^3$ is not a plane. Actually you haven't explained why  $Ax +By = D - Cz$ is a plane. You only showed that it is a ruled surface.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, if $A = B = C = 0$, then the solution set will be all of $\Bbb R^3$ (if $D = 0$) or the empty set (if $D \neq 0$).

So, suppose not, that is, that at least one of $A, B, C$ is nonzero; by relabeling if necessary, $C$ is. Rearranging gives
$$z = -\frac{A}{C} x - \frac{B}{C} y + \frac{D}{C},$$
so the solution set is the graph of an affine function of $x, y$, and hence is a plane.

One *can* specify a line by a suitable pair of such equations,
$$A_i x + B_i y + C_i z = D_i, \qquad i = 1, 2.$$
(This system defines a line iff (1) at least one of $A_i, B_i, C_i$ is nonzero, for both $i = 1, 2$, and (2) the coefficient vectors ${\bf A}_1 := (A_1, B_1, C_1), {\bf A}_2 := (A_2, B_2, C_2)$ are linearly independent. Condition (2) is equivalent to ${\bf A}_1 \times {\bf A}_2 \neq 0$. Indeed, the line is parallel to that cross product.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you’re not surprised that $z=0$ describes the $(x,y)$-plane: all points $(x,y,0)$ in space; nor that $y=0$ describes the $(x,z)$-plane: all $(x,0,z)$ in space. What *line* could either of these equations possibly describe?

Actually, there is a way of describing a line in space by a single equation, as long as you’re talking about *real* points only, but it’s a cheat. The equation $y^2+z^2=0$ describes the $x$-axis, because for real numbers, the only way that a sum of squares can be zero is for the individual summands each to be zero, so this equation boils down to $y^2=0$ together with $z^2=0$, inother words $y=0$ and $z=0$.

Answer (score -1):

If we fix a value of x and y, we get only one value of z. i.e x and y can take any real value but then z will be fixed.This is the algebraic way of stating a plane.

Comment: So $x+y+z^3=1$ is a plane?